debian bookworm nvidia-settings slow glx framebuffer configurations detected?
I have a little problem to interpret the message in nvidia-settings.

Background is I have render problem in some contextmenues. (Here firefox-esr)

Some info (hardware)
nvidia-detect 
Detected NVIDIA GPUs:
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM206GLM [Quadro M2200 Mobile] [10de:1436] (rev a1)

Checking card:  NVIDIA Corporation GM206GLM [Quadro M2200 Mobile] (rev a1)
Your card is supported by all driver versions.
Your card is also supported by the Tesla 470 drivers series.
It is recommended to install the
    nvidia-driver

More longer info paste-info
Desktop is mate (X11 session) windowmanager marco without composit.
alex@Taomon:~$ glxinfo | grep render
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: Quadro M2200/PCIe/SSE2
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_KHR_shader_subgroup, GL_KTX_buffer_region, GL_NVX_conditional_render, 
    GL_NV_compute_program5, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
    GL_NV_path_rendering, GL_NV_path_rendering_shared_edge, 
    GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, 
    GL_KHR_shader_subgroup, GL_KTX_buffer_region, GL_NVX_conditional_render, 
    GL_NV_compute_program5, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
    GL_NV_path_rendering, GL_NV_path_rendering_shared_edge, 
    GL_EXT_multisample_compatibility, GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture, 
    GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture2, 
    GL_EXT_raster_multisample, GL_EXT_read_format_bgra, GL_EXT_render_snorm, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_conservative_raster, GL_NV_copy_buffer, 
    GL_NV_packed_float_linear, GL_NV_path_rendering, 
    GL_NV_path_rendering_shared_edge, GL_NV_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap, 
    GL_OVR_multiview_multisampled_render_to_texture

